# RuntimeError: ERROR 000824: The tool is not licensed

Tags: arcpy, spatial-analyst, arcgis-license-manager, error-000824

I am reopening an issue about:

> RuntimeError: ERROR 000824: The tool is not licensed

Since I could not find the answer to my problem in previous issues.

I am running a script.py in Anaconda. The scripts requires `arcpy` that I can import to python.

When I run the script, everything seems alright until the end where I get the following error:

`File "C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.5\ArcPy\arcpy\sa\Functions.py", line 4483, in Times
    in_raster_or_constant2)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.5\ArcPy\arcpy\sa\Utils.py", line 53, in swapper
    result = wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.5\ArcPy\arcpy\sa\Functions.py", line 4480, in Wrapper
    ["Times", in_raster_or_constant1, in_raster_or_constant2])
RuntimeError: ERROR 000824: The tool is not licensed.`

I have checked my extensions in ArcMap and all of them are ticked. In addition, I have a license for ArcGIS that I had previously authorized.

I cannot figure it out and I don't know which tools are not licensed.

Answer (score 3):

Include a line in your script checking out the license for the appropriate extension, such as Spatial Analyst or Network Analyst:

```
arcpy.CheckOutExtension("[Extension name]")
```

The Esri Technical article on this error explains in more detail:
https://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000013100

> Error: 000824: The tool is not licensed Error Message Running a Python
>   script to launch geoprocessing tools returns the error:
>
> Error: "000824: The tool is not licensed." Cause There are two
>   possible reasons for this issue:
>
> The ArcGIS for Desktop version installed is not licensed for tools in
>   an extension. The extension the tools are in is not checked out in the
>   script. If this is the case, the tool is not available for use in the
>   Python environment.

Based on the rest of your error, the issue is coming up when using ["Times"](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.5/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/times.htm#C_GUID-B409A84F-A954-4DE7-9726-F816356E3848), which requires Spatial Analyst in ArcGIS Desktop 10.5 (If using ArcGIS Pro, it also works with Image Analyst / 3D Analyst licenses). I pared back the official code snippet to show that tool being checked out, below.

```
# Requirements: Spatial Analyst Extension

# Import system modules

# Set environment settings

# Check out the ArcGIS Spatial Analyst extension license
arcpy.CheckOutExtension("Spatial")
```